# pass instance of generic type »as is«

Tags: typescript, generics

Consider this sample code which results in a compile error:

```
interface Options<T extends string> {
  name: T
}

class A<T extends string> {
  constructor(readonly options: Options<T>){};
}


class B {
  constructor(readonly a: A) {}
//                  Error ~ Generic type 'A<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
}


const 
  a = new A<'test'>({ name: 'test' }),
  b = new B(a)
;
```

Is there a way to tell typescript, that the generic type of `a: A` should be the one `a` was created with?

I am trying to follow the dependency injection pattern here. Therefore I need to »pass the created instance `a` around«, including its generic setup.

I guess I am scrambling some OOP concepts here and try to gain something what makes no sense on a conceptual level, but if not, what would be the best way to come around this issue,

Answer (score 0):

Since `Class A<T extends string>` has generic parameter you need to specify it.
You can define default value to the generic parameter to fix the compile time error.

```
class A<T extends string = string>
```

> Is there a way to tell typescript, that the generic type of a: A should be the one a was created with?

Since parameter is passed to constructor of B at runtime, typescript compiler cannot identify the generic type. (Note: After compilation there is no any generic types)

### Typescript Code

```js
interface Options<T extends string> {
  name: T
}

// If T is not specified then T = string
class A<T extends string = string> {
  constructor(readonly options: Options<T>){};
}


class B {
  constructor(readonly a: A) {}
}


const 
  a = new A<'test'>({ name: 'test' }),
  b = new B(a)
;
```

### Compiled Code

```js
var A = /** @class */ (function () {
    function A(options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
    ;
    return A;
}());
var B = /** @class */ (function () {
    function B(a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    return B;
}());
var a = new A({ name: 'test' }), b = new B(a);
```

---

### Updated

Just make `class B` also generic. Compiler will choose type as you want.

```js
interface Options<T extends string> {
  name: T
}

class A<T extends string> {
  constructor(readonly options: Options<T>){};
}

class B<T extends string> {
  constructor(readonly a: A<T>) {}
}


const 
  a = new A<'test'>({ name: 'test' }),
  b = new B(a)
;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But that creates a default type value, which is always string, if not provided.

Comment: Yeah @philipp, I mentioned that. What about implementing class B as generic class.

Comment: @philipp , See the Updated section. Thanks!

Comment: That is basically where I started and requires to hand over the generic parameter. But, nevertheless, even if `B` would be generic, within `B` one just cannot know the concrete type of the generic parameter - because it is a parameter… Creating a global type fixes the issue.